# Ubuntu 16.04 - Reboot after a “sudo mv /* .”, I'm struggling with the reboot, currently initramfs does'n't find root in etc/fstab

Tags: 16.04, mount, reboot

Yesterday I have make a nooby-break using `sudo / .`, meaning "hey move all my boot files and all in my user session tree folder", I have forgot the dot behind my slash as following `./` .

I'm trying to reboot and I have since followed several progression points, here an abstract of my previous step:

- firstly I have tried to boot with a USB-live with Ubuntu on it. But i couldn't login neither access a `tty` since there was a problem with `grub` or something like that so I have open `grub` and fallen on `grub-rescue`.
- Then I have remembered that I have moved all my boot-files inside the tree so I have started to seek for how to move-back theses files.
- I have meanwhile find a topic in which someone have done something similar to me, he explains in how to connect and prefix the root in grub rescue, here the topic: [grub rescue / move folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504274/grub-rescue-move-folder).
- I have hence managed on Grub rescue to set my root and prefix on the folder in which I have moved all my boot-files.
- Then I have emerged from grub rescue to grub, and after some googling, I have passed the following commands in grub:

  ```
  grub> linux /home/path_to_boot/boot/vmlinuz-3.xx.x-67-generic
  grub> initrd /home/path_to_boot/boot/initrd.img-3.xx.x-67-generic
  grub> boot
  ```

Now my computer have started the boot and manage some steps, then returns me three errors:

- firstly

  > on initramfs: mounting can't find /root in /etc/fstab/mounting.
- secondly

  > /root/run failed: no such file or directory
- finally

  > target file system doesn't have requested /sbin/init or /bin/init maybe -I have noted sbin but usually is rather bin?

Here a snapashot of my current situation, you will see at the top of my image the list of folder in my "/" mount directory - `ls` command.

[image]

So that it, I don't know what should I do in particular, I'm very happy having manage grub rescue, now I would have advice about how handle my situation furthermore.

Any hint would be great, Thanks!

Comment: At this point, wouldn't it be faster and more secure to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: At the least, post the complete commands you ran, not just the "bad part"

Comment: @Jos yes but using my usb: to ibstall, its put me on black screen with underscore flashing; to try ubuntu, it put me on a login but my credentials aren t recognized -I have moved them! So even using my usb doesnt work

Comment: Please try again an show us 'ls -l' in the first grub booting step. You missed some important parts and cannot work like this.

Comment: Okay I retry and go back, what do you mean by first grub bootting step? On my first grub rescue it returns.me a list of (hX, msdosY)

Comment: Reinstall the OS, next time pay more attention... never drink and sudo.
If you broke the USB too flash it again, make sure your UEFI boots from the USB.

Comment: Yes I m booting from USB now,  aah, in all case I have learn that sudo really mean being behind the security's shield of the system